# Calculate multiplicative inverse of positive real number

Tags: c, algorithm, math

I wanted to calculate the multiplicative inverse of a positive real number without using division. After reading through various pages on Newton Raphson method, i implemented the following code for calculating the inverse:

```
#define PRECISION 0.1e-5
double inverse(double num) {
    double ans = num;
    while (ans * num > 1 + PRECISION || ans * num < 1 - PRECISION) {
        ans = ans * (2 - num * ans);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Now, the problem is, I actually do not get the inverse value. The loop goes on infinitely.

So, **1st** thing I noticed was: 
The value of `ans` become negative, I added a statement 
`if (ans < 0) ans *= -1;` 
so that `ans` remains positive always.

**2nd** point to be noticed:
If my initialization for `ans = 0.5` then I get the correct answer for a few values of `num` = `(1, 2, 3, 5)`.

So, my assumption is, that the implementation isn't working because of inappropriate initialization of the variable `ans`.

So, finally my questions:

**1**.Can this method actually be used to calculate inverse of all positive real numbers?

**2**.If yes, then are there any conditions required for the initial value assumed when using Newton Raphson method? 

**3**.Is there any other better method to calculate reciprocal without using division?

### **EDIT:**

Thanks for the answer. So, as mentioned in the answer, I changed my initial value of `ans` to `PRECISION` and it works! Also, now as the initial value is good for particular max limit on `num`, `ans` never becomes negative, so no need for the negative checking condition that I had added initially.

So, this is the working code (atleast works for the input I have given.)

```
double inverse(double num) {
    // Added to make it valid for all inputs.
    // For a too large number under the precision constraint, the answer is 0.
    if (num > 999999)
        return 0;
    double ans = PRECISION;
    while (ans * num > 1 + PRECISION || ans * num < 1 - PRECISION) {
        ans = ans * (2 - num * ans);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Minor comment: changing 
`ans = 2 * ans - num * ans * ans`
to
`ans = ans * (2 - num * ans)`
should give you a bit better numerical stability.

Comment: You mention that you added a statement `if(ans<0) ans *= -1;`, but it is not there in your sample code. Where did you add the statement?

Comment: The expression: ans = 2 * ans - num * ans * ans that you get from taylor approximation is valid only for cases where "1/ans" is close to "num".

Comment: Just noted that initially "ans = num;
ans = 2*ans-num*ans*ans; => ans = 2 * ans - 3 * ans = -1 * ans

Comment: See the edited section of answer below

Comment: @uba: The code snippet that i added was as originally explained on the websites After noting the points, i added that extra line later, hence not indicated in the code snippet. Edited the question to make it more clear.
Christopher: That doesn't make a difference because of the precedence rules. However, i have changed it for clear understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pick the initial approximation from (0, 2/num). If you pick it from the other side of 2/num, the method may not converge: the approximation will overshoot 0 and the sequence will tend to -∞.

To arrive at the interval, let's see where `ans*(2-num*ans)` changes sign: it becomes negative when 2-num*ans < 0, or when ans > 2/num. So initially `ans` should be less than 2/num.

To be able to pick a good initial approximation you have to know a little about how floating point numbers are expressed. Typically computers use x = s*m*2<sup>e</sup>, where s is the sign, m ("mantissa") is in (0.5, 1) and e ("exponent") is an integer. Now 1/x = s*1/m * 2<sup>-e</sup>, so the problem is reduced to calculating the inverse of a number in range (0.5, 1), and in that range you can use for example 1 as the initial guess. Apparently the optimal initial guess in that range is [48/17 - 32/17*m](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Newton.E2.80.93Raphson_division).

One initial guess that should work for all numbers s*m*2<sup>e</sup> is s*2<sup>-e</sup>. In C this can be calculated as:

```
double ans = num;
// Initial guess: ans = 2**(-floor(log num))
long int *t = (long int*)(&ans);
*t = (*t & (0x1l<<63)) | (~*t & (0x3FFl << 52)) - (0x1l << 52);
      /* sign */              /* negative exponent */
```

(Beware: I haven't checked the edge conditions.)

Comment: Hey thanks for the 1st point that you made i.e. making initial approximation from (0, 1/num). So, i just set my initial value to PRECISION and then continue and works !! thanks. But, how did you get that the initial approximation should be less than (0, 1/num) ? Is it applicable for other applications of Newton-Raphson method too?

Comment: @aslan3893, I drew a graph of the function and deduced that there's no chance of overshoot if you pick the initial guess from (0, 1/num). Actually some values greater than 1/num will also work.

Comment: Turns out, the safe range for the initial guess is (0, 2/num). See update.

Answer (score 0):

To approximate the reciprocal of x, using only multiplication and subtraction, one can guess a number y, and then repeatedly replace y with 2y − xy^2. Once the change in y becomes (and stays) sufficiently small, y is an approximation of the reciprocal of x.

ans = (2*ans)- (num*ans*ans);

Please add parantheses and try

In constructive mathematics, for a real number x to have a reciprocal, it is not sufficient that x ≠ 0. There must instead be given a rational number r such that 0 < r < |x|. In terms of the approximation algorithm in the previous paragraph, this is needed to prove that the change in y will eventually become arbitrarily small.  **=> Multiplicative inverse of all real numbers cannot be deducted by this method**

A ring in which every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse is a division ring; likewise an algebra in which this holds is a division algebra.

Would u like to use modulo? In modular arithmetic, the modular multiplicative inverse of a is also defined: it is the number x such that ax ≡ 1 (mod n). This multiplicative inverse exists if and only if a and n are coprime.

_EDIT_*_*____

Just noted that initially 
    ans = num;
    ans = 2*ans-num*ans*ans; => ans = 2 * ans - 3 * ans = -1 * ans

So it will always be a negative value.. Believe that it is not a good thought to initialize to num. Try setting ans to 1

Comment: Adding parentheses does not make a difference here.

Comment: i was not sure.. thats why i asked to try

Comment: I'm all for mathematical rigour, but (a) `double` doesn't actually represent arbitrary real numbers anyway, every value of `double` is rational, and so the questioner has asked for a stronger condition than he actually needs. (b) however the questioner chooses to construct "the reals", I think we can safely assume that the rationals are dense in the domain of the question.

Comment: Just noted that initially ans = num; ans = 2*ans-num*ans*ans; => ans = 2 * ans - 3 * ans = -1 * ans

So it will always be a negative value.. Believe that it is not a good thought to initialize to num. Try setting ans to 1

Comment: setting the initial condition to 1 doesn't help. It runs into infinite loops.